# Polymer: Styling <content> elements with custom CSS properties

Tags: css, polymer, shadow-dom

I have a question relating to styling  with the ::content selector and custom CSS properties. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

This is a simplified version of the problem. Here I have a Polymer component that uses a content tag. The content will always be a paper-input:

```
<template>
  <style>
    #container ::content paper-input {
      --paper-input-container-focus-color: #ddd;
      margin: 8px;
    }     
  </style>
  <div id="container">
    <content></content>
  </div>
</template>
```

When I test this, the margin is applied but the custom css property is not.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish impossible?

Comment: Try adding style is="custom-style"  to your style tag

Comment: Did you see https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#styling-distributed-children-content about custom css properties, maybe it is related

Comment: which version of Polymer are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using Polymer 1.6+. You can switch on `native css` using [useNativeCSSProperties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/release-notes#release-160) to make this work. And if you are using 1.7 then i'd recommend you to use `slot` instead of `content` as that is what polymer is migrating to in V2.0+ and it is part of `shadow dom v1`. Though not sure if it'll work in `IE` or not as in IE `useNativeCssProperties` has no effect

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<script>
  window.Polymer = {
    lazyRegister: true,
    useNativeCSSProperties: true
  }
</script>
<link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
<dom-module id="light-dom">
  <template>
    <style>
      #container ::slotted(paper-input) {
        --paper-input-container-focus-color: #ddd;
      }
    </style>
    <div id="container">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'light-dom'
  })
</script>




<light-dom>
  <paper-input label="hello"></paper-input>
</light-dom>
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response. Currently using an older version of polymer (1.2.3), but we'll be advancing to 1.7 soon.

I've been reading that setting useNativeCSSProperties to 'true' will allow this approach in most browsers. 

That being said, apparently Edge and Safari don't currently support css properties. Since those browsers will fallback to Polymers shim I'm assuming that they wouldn't render the above example correctly.